# Are sys._getframe().f_builtins and __builtins__.__dict__ equivalent?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I am correct:

- `sys._getframe().f_builtins` are the builtin objects in the top frame of the current call stack; and
- `__builtins__.__dict__` are the builtin objects in the current module.

What differences are there between the values of `sys._getframe().f_builtins` and `__builtins__.__dict__`? Do they always have the same value, i.e. the same builtin objects?

Answer (score 3):

> What differences are between the values of `sys._getframe().f_builtins` and `__builtins__.__dict__`? Do they always have the same value, i.e. the same builtin objects?

Yes.

Builtin names in Python stay the same across scopes and namespaces. That's why their called *"builtins"*; You can access them from anywhere because they're built into the interpreter. Unless you explicitly changed the builtin mappings, they'll be the same.

But not just that, they both point to the *same* builtins mapping. That means changes to `__builtins__.__dict__` will change `sys._get_frame().f_builtins` and visa versa.

This can also be tested by a simple example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> frame = sys._getframe()
>>> 
>>> frame.f_builtins == __builtins__.__dict__
True
>>> frame.f_builtins['abc'] = 3
>>> frame.f_builtins['abc']
3
>>> frame.f_builtins == __builtins__.__dict__
True
>>>
```

When we add a new builtin name to `frame.f_builtins`, `__builtins__.__dict__` changed as well.

**Note:** `__builtins__` is a CPython implementation detail, and may not exist in other Python implementations. So don't rely on it. Instead, use the [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/builtins.html#module-builtins) module.

Comment: Thanks. Does `==` in `frame.f_builtins == __builtins__.__dict__`  check if the two operands bind to the same object, or  check if the objects binded to the two operands have the same value/content?

Comment: @Tim It compares if the `dict`s have the same contents. You can try this out yourself by creating two dictionaries objects with the same content and seeing if their equal.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any case where an execution frame's builtins (as assessed through its `f_builtins` attribute) would be different than just accessing the `__builtin__` module.  However, it's important to note that `f_builtins` could be different if you have some custom code manipulating it.

According to [this source](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/SpelunkingFBuiltins):

> The directly accessible ways are to use eval() or exec and specify a
>   'globals' dictionary with a **builtins** member. If present, this
>   becomes the builtins for the code, shows up in f_builtins in frames,
>   and so on. Any code frame with a non-standard value for f_builtins is
>   a 'restricted' frame, and various bits of the CPython innards behave
>   differently (usually they forbid various operations, for example
>   setting attributes on classes). In turn all of this seems to be
>   present to support the now-deprecated rexec.py module, which attempts
>   to (you guessed it) restrict what some untrusted Python code can do.